# Spacing too small above footnote

Tags: spacing

Sometimes working with footnotes and `center` environment together, a weird behavior would happen that the spacing between the end of `center` environment and footnote is too small. The following MWE produces this weird result. What accounts for this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
This is a dummy text.\footnote{This is a footnote.}
\vspace{0.9\textheight}
\begin{center}
    \fbox{Why is the spacing so small?}
\end{center}

\section{Why??}

\end{document}
```

[image]

But if I replace the `section` with natural paragraph, it all goes right.

Comment: Actually, this is a very good question

Answer (score 3):

This is a mis-feature in latex, but may be hard to fix (in a compatible way)

The spacing above the footnote rule is

```
...\glue 10.0 plus 3.0 minus 5.0
...\glue -15.0 plus -3.0 minus -5.0
...\glue 9.0 plus 4.0 minus 2.0
...\kern -3.0
...\rule(0.4+0.0)x137.9979
```

where you see it is small as there is a -15pt inserted

This is latex trying to merge the space after a center with the space before a section heading, when there are two adjacent display spaces latex avoids getting them both and arranges that the total is the larger of the two (usually)

Here though the space gets adjusted assuming the section heading will be below the center but once the footnote is inserted there is no room and the section heading is pushed to the next page.....

The simplest workaround when that happens is to `\clearpage` before the section heading, then LaTeX does not consider that the heading may be after the center and you get the intended space.

```
\documentclass{article}
\showoutput
\begin{document}
This is a dummy text.\footnote{This is a footnote.}

\vspace{0.9\textheight}
\begin{center}
    \fbox{Why is the spacing so small?}

\end{center}

\clearpage
\section{Why??}

\end{document}
```

[image]